# How to re-use an already installed package in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I installed couple of packages for 'Project A' (e.g bootstrap) assuming that it will be available for all subsequent projects.  But when a new meteor project 'Project B' was created, `meteor list` showed only default packages.  So my assumption that meteor packages are like ruby gems available globally is incorrect.  As I work offline every now and then, Is there a way I can manually copy/re-use installed packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are similar to gems. Packages are installed in `~/.meteor/packages`, in precompiled form. They can be installed globally this way.

When you add a package to your project it will essentially copy the package from there into your build-cache directory hidden in the `.meteor` directory of your project.

To install a package locally where you can easily re-use it you would have to clone the github repository of the package and place the output in the `/packages` directory of your Meteor app.

For example for bootstrap, `twbs:bootstrap` you would clone this reposistory: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap, into a directory like `/packages/twbs:bootstrap` (name doesn't matter if its defined in the package.js file on the repository.

In general you can easily re-use a package without the hassle of adding it in manually like so. It's better to use the global packages which are kept up to date.

The trouble comes with being offline. If you use a local package its nearly guaranteed to always work. Whereas the global ones can give a bit of trouble once in a while when you try to add a package in as meteor tries to check the package is up to date, especially where npm packages are involved with the package.

To keep it short if you added a package in using `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` you should most likely be able to add it to another project using the same command. Only if you keep your packages & meteor up to date.